# How to Decrypt encrypted php code?

Tags: decode

How to decrypt the encrypted php code with following:

```
eval(key_variable(base64_decode('some text')));
```

this used a keywords instead of gzinflate.

Comment: By replacing eval with echo?

Comment: I want to get souce code of this base64_encode

Comment: base64 is encoding not encryption.